# How to display bitmap made from byte array by BitmapFactory in an ImageView

Tags: android, bitmap, byte

I have a 160 x 160 pixel bitmap and a 4 byte-per-pixel byte array. Whatever I put in the byte array the ImageView stays white space.

I need a code snippet showing a byte array displaying something, anything, in the ImageView.

I use BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray to build the bitmap.

Many thanks

Comment: `I need a code snippet showing a byte array displaying something, anything, in the ImageView.` this doesn't work this way. First you show us your code, and then we try to help you to fix it.

Comment: You ask your question with the problem that you have problem to solve, not asking for the code.

Comment: `I have a 160 x 160 pixel bitmap`. Nice. Then put that in your ImageView. One assigment will do.

Comment: `Whatever I put in the byte array` Not a good idea. You cannot just put some values there.

Answer (score 0):

The buffer is filled from an input stream from a remote device through Bluetooth.

Translation of that stream is a whole other set of problems which will be solved eventually.

What needs to be displayed id a 16 greyscale fingerprint. What gets displayed is white space - there's no starting point to fix anything if its just white space.

The code to put the buffer into the bitmap into the ImageView is:

```
Bitmap bmp - BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgBuffer2, 0, imgBuffer2.length, options);
iVfprint.setImageBitmap(bmp);
iVfprint.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

The options are

```
options.inScreenDensity = (int) metrics.density;
options.inMutable = true;
```

But they have no effect since nothing is displayed

The ImageView has width and height of 160px and no other attributes other than position.

The buffer is 102400 bytes long. 4 bytes per pixel